# Using a web proxy to modify the html response coming back from a website

Tags: javascript, html, proxy, client-side, httpwebresponse

Background:
I am looking for a way to insert a `<script>` tag into a webpage for which I do not have access to the server-side source code.

Question:
My organization uses [Blue Coat ProxySG](https://www.bluecoat.com/products/proxysg) for our web proxy solution and I am wondering if there is a way to have the proxy modify the html coming back from the site host before it passes it down to the client. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: I've wondered this too. I don't think it can be done and I have yet to find any solution that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from the Blue Coat ProxySG with current SGOS code.

You can create custom exception html pages on the ProxySG, if that is more of what you are trying to accomplish. So, if you are unable to access the server, you can have the ProxySG serve the exception page. This is not modifying the html from the site host, but providing it's own html which is customized to your needs.

Comment: Thanks bentek. Yes, I am aware of custom exception pages.  The reason why I need to insert a script tag into the html coming back from the website host is because I am trying to implement some custom front-end functionality by running a javascript program on top of the website. This is a vendor hosted website and they will not implement our enhancement requests so I am looking for a way to handle it client side without having access to their source code.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is something the web  proxy will be able to help me with though.  I just wanted tap into the community to confirm.

Comment: If anyone is aware of another means of modifying an html response before it is downloaded to the client, it would be helpful.  I'm thinking it could be handled at the network layer using wireshark or something but a solution like that could get pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus, I believe a load-balancer with advanced configuration from a vendor such as F5 has the capability to modify layer-7 packets to insert/remove and modify various things.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. We use Citrix Netscaler here. I'll inquire with my team to see if our web proxy is being load balanced and if it supports this functionality.

Comment: Not Yet. I've been swamped with higher priority projects.